# Spring 4.0 MVC RequestMapping at class and method level

Tags: java, spring-mvc, request, restful-url

I am new to annotation and exploring out things. In my sample program .. a simple hello world using annotations in spring 4.0.

This is the controller file code I have two annotated RequestMapping entries i.e one at class level and another at method level :

```
package com.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/Hybrid")
public class HybridController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getDemo(String name) {
        System.out.println("/MVC/Demo");
        return "helloworld" ;
    }
```

}

If i put only the class level @RequestMapping it works with this url connecting to 
    .../SpringRS/Hybrid
 or just only the method level to connect using 
    .../SpringRS/test it works perfectly and displays me the helloworld.jsp.

But when i try to put class and method request mapping together and invoke using this url :             .../SpringRS/Hybrid/test, it don't work.

Could some one explain what i need to make it work?.

View resolver mapping:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com" />
<mvc:annotation-driven />

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix">
        <value>WEB-INF/views/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
    </bean>
```

Comment: Are you sure you don't have conflicting URL mappings defined? Can you enable debug logging for spring because that should tell you which controller is mapped to which URL.

Comment: Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11203907/spring-controllers-url-request-mapping-not-working-as-expected

Answer (score 0):

I think in your web.xml you have url-pattern for DispatcherServlet as /Hybrid which maps  exactly to your annotation at class level.If your request is for .../Hybrid it is picked up by the DispatcherServlet since it is an exact match. If your request is for .../Hybrid/test it is not at all picked up by the DispatcherServlet. Instead if your url-pattern ends with a wildcard like /something/* the request .../something/Hybrid/test will first be picked up by the DispatcherServlet and then handed over to the controller to be resolved.